# GRUB boot error, getting efi/ as only folder

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

So I'm completely new to Linux and found out that I needed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer for a class this semester. The laptop I'm taking with me to school is a Surface Pro 4 and I have a 240GB micro-SD card in it that I'm using to store the OS.

I decided to try and dual-boot it, so I looked up some tutorials and did all the things to install and finally got to the restart portion of Ubuntu install. After rebooting I ran into the Grub screen.So I googled it and did all the ls (hd0,1)/ stuff but I can't find the same stuff that it shows in all the tutorials. All I find is 3 of them have "unidentified file format" which makes sense, and (hd0,1) has efi/ under it. Thats it though. There's no boot/ or anything.

Would (hd0,1) be the partition I should do all the other commands too?

Comment: That's not what should be happening. Normally, grub would show you an entry for WIndows and an entry for Ubuntu, along with some other options. You should be able to boot by just selecting it with the arrow keys and pressing Enter.

Comment: Did you leave Windows fast start up on which is just hibernation. Then Linux NTFS driver cannot parse partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  Post this from terminal in live installer: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: No I disabled fast startup before starting